# Not using 'localhost' in HOST for development with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My problem is quite simple: I would like to avoid using `localhost` at the end of my `HOST` env variable with create-react-app. However it seems that if the URL doesn't end with `.localhost`, the script will try to resolve the URL against a DNS server.

I would like to avoid that and just use the same URL domain as my backend server is using, to avoid CORS problems (and I wish not to configure my backend to allow CORS because that's not how the production infrastructure is).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use some custom domain locally, without resolving it agains a DNS server, you can add that domain to your `hosts` file.

Location of `hosts` file on Windows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Location of `hosts` file on Mac:

```
/etc/hosts
```

You can modify the `hosts` file by adding the following line to it:

```
127.0.0.1       yourcustomdomain.com
```

This will bind `yourcustomdomain.com` to your local IP. Now you can use `yourcustomdomain.com` in your `create-react-app`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I have an interrogation though: when using .localhost, I don't need to edit my hosts. Why do I need to if I don't use .localhost ? I thought hosts files did not support top-level domains but only exact matches.

Comment: @Jeahel If you take a look at your `hosts` file, you will find a comment saying `# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.`. `localhost` is mapped to the local IP by default.

Comment: Oh I never paid attention to that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The true problem you're facing here is CORS. The standard solution for this is actually to just proxy your request, so that they're hitting from the same origin. Webpack has a clean way to do this. See this blog by facebook: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

This has gotten incredibly easy to do now. All you need to do is add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`. For example -

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```